# How to generate auto increase UNIQUE text ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been given a task to create a table with where the CustomerID will have to be in text(Varchar) and must be unique.
I created the table using the example bellow (Using calculated field). I was told that the table should not contain any calculated filed and the LEN of the CustomerID column should not exceed varchar(14)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer(
    CustID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    customerID AS CAST(CustID AS VARCHAR(200))+LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()),8),
    LastName varchar(300),
    FirstName varchar(300)NOT NULL
);
```

Guys any idea on how I can create the table with unique cutomerID without using calculated field?

the Output of the ID should look like

```
19DA9C895
2341F6E59
3B713A0CD
```

it can be letters or mixture of letters and numbers 
Thanks

Comment: So... What *should* your ID look like? Why the (odd) requirements (for example the table containing no calculated column)? What's wrong with `int IDENTITY`? Is this homework?

Comment: Is it going to be populated manually or from some other source?  Why not use an INT IDENTITY or UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Comment: `'19DA9C895'` isn't 14 characters. Are you saying it can be less? I'd suggest to at least keep it a uniform length. Honestly though, this request just seems completely nonsensical.

Comment: This is a truly bizarre requirement with some oddball restrictions. This is NOT a good way to deal with data at all. About the only thing you could do would be to create a function to generate this nonsensical key and check the existing data if it is already in use or not.

Comment: Well, the typical case of an ignorant (client, boss?) asking for impossible tasks that make no sense. If you can't use Identity or a calculated field, you could use a GUID (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) but the length is 32 characters so you are out of luck.

Comment: Some very strange requirements.  Is this homework?

Comment: @Paparazzi this is not homework. This is real requirement from the business, where i work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sequence and a default value for `customer_id` column. The sequence value is an integer and `customer_id` is a character string, but you can derive the `customer_id` value from the sequence value using an expression like `RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varchar(14)), 14)`

Please, run the following code to see how it works:

```
use tempdb;
GO

CREATE SEQUENCE customer_id_seq START WITH 1 AS bigint;

GO

SELECT RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varchar(14)), 14)

GO
CREATE TABLE customers
(
    customer_id varchar(14) DEFAULT (RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varchar(14)), 14)),
    customer_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_customers PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
)

GO

INSERT INTO customers(customer_name) VALUES ('ACME');
INSERT INTO customers(customer_name) VALUES ('Marvel');

GO

INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name)
VALUES (RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varchar(14)), 14), 'Fox');

INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name)
VALUES (RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varchar(14)), 14), 'Columbia');

GO
SELECT * FROM customers
```

Note that you can insert new rows without specifying `customer_id` column. But you can if you want. If you specify `customer_id` column you should use the expression `RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varchar(14)), 14)`.

EDIT:

A better option would be to use the expression `CONVERT(varchar(14), CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varbinary(7)), 2)`. Because `customer_id` domain would be longer since it would contain not only digits but A, B, C, D and F characters.

The table would be:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
    customer_id varchar(14) DEFAULT (CONVERT(varchar(14), CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varbinary(7)), 2)),
    customer_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_customers PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
)
```

Insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO customers(customer_name) VALUES ('ACME');
INSERT INTO customers(customer_name) VALUES ('Marvel');

GO

INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name)
VALUES (CONVERT(varchar(14), CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varbinary(7)), 2), 'Fox');

INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name)
VALUES (CONVERT(varchar(14), CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR customer_id_seq AS varbinary(7)), 2), 'Columbia');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AFTER INSERT trigger that looks at the value of `CustID` in `inserted`, and then populates `CustomerID` with some translation of that value (like Hexadecimal or any other formula you'd care to follow).

Comment: You cannot do that because CustomerID is the primary key, so it must be populated first.

Comment: @JesúsLópez  What makes you say that?   In the CREATE TABLE script in the question, CustID is the primary key, not CustomerID.   Did I miss something in a comment somewhere?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. However CustomerID must be unique. That constraint is enforced on insert. If it's not satisfied your trigger will not fire. So, what's the point of your trigger?. You need to provide the unique CustomerID value upfront.

Comment: Again, I don't see any evidence that there is an actual unique constraint on that column in the table.  The unique-ness can be enforced, therefore, in the trigger code.   That column doesn't even have a NOT NULL on it.

Comment: What about the title of the question?

Comment: Yes the title of the question says that the final CustomerID value needs to be unique.   But there is nothing about a constraint that is enforced on insert.

Comment: Triggers are not the right place to enforce uniqueness, unique constraints are the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to do here. Your post says "auto increase", not sure what that means. But your sample output looks like random data. So I put this together to demonstrate how you can generate a 14 character random string with some criteria. I am using a tally table here to make this a bit easier. You can read more about them here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

I keep a tally table as a view on my system. The code looks like this.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

The other challenging piece here is we want get random values while using a function. This is a bit of a puzzle because the best way to get a random value is by using order by NEWID(). But you can't do that in a function. But all is not lost. We can create a view that returns a NEWID() to us and use that as the order predicate. Here is that view.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.RandomID
AS
SELECT NewId() AS RandomID
```

Now we just need our function. This is not pretty but the requirement is a bit offbeat as well. We need to get 14 random characters and we have to ensure that the value does not already exist in the Customer table.

```
create function CreateAbsurdKey()
returns varchar(14) as
begin

    declare @Key varchar(14) = '';

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    select top 1 @Key = @Key + CHAR(t.N)
    from cteTally t
    where 
    (t.N >= 48 AND t.N <= 57)
        OR
    (t.N >= 65 AND t.N <= 90)
    order by (select RandomID from RandomID)

    --This will use recursion if the generated value already exists
    while exists(select * from Customer where customerID = @key)
    begin
        select @key = dbo.CreateAbsurdKey()
    end

    return @Key
end
```

Last but not least would be how you might be able to use this.

```
insert Customer
select dbo.CreateAbsurdKey()
    , 'Lange'
    , 'Sean'
```

You can run that repeatedly and it will continue to insert with new values for customerID.

```
select * from Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer:
To guarantee the uniqueness, it must be ensured that it does not exist in another register

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
CustID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
customerID VARCHAR(14) default CONVERT(VARCHAR(14), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(14), 2 ),
field1 VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO Customer (field1 ) VALUES ('Customer1')
INSERT INTO Customer (field1 ) VALUES ('Customer2')
INSERT INTO Customer (field1 ) VALUES ('Customer3')
INSERT INTO Customer (field1 ) VALUES ('Customer4')
INSERT INTO Customer (field1 ) VALUES ('Customer5')

SELECT * FROM Customer
GO
DROP TABLE Customer
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer(
    CustID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    customerID uniqueidentifier constraint [df_customer_customerID] DEFAULT(NEWID()),  --NEWID should be as unique as it gets????
    LastName varchar(300),
    FirstName varchar(300)NOT NULL
)


declare @i int = 1
while @i < 100000
begin
    insert dbo.Customer(LastName,FirstName)
    select 'Last_' + convert(varchar(10),@i), 'First_' + convert(varchar(10),@i)
    set @i = @i + 1
end

select customerID, count(1) from dbo.Customer group by customerID having count(1) > 1
select count(1) from dbo.Customer
```